# How can I terminate a loop when pressing Enter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program that repeatedly asks the user to enter an integer or to terminate input by pressing Enter key, and then prints the even integers from those numbers entered.

Now, I am pretty much done with this program, I've mentioned the code I've come up with below. I am facing only one problem: how can I terminate the program when the users presses the Enter key?

```
def evenMem(aList):
    mnew = []
    for i in aList:
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            mnew.append(i)
    return mnew

def main():
    m = []
    while True:
        n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        m.append(n)
    print(evenMem(m))

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're using Python 3.x, make the while loop look like this:

```
while True:
    line = input('Enter a number: ')
    if not line:
        break
    n = int(line)
    m.append(n)
```

You might want to surround the conversion to `int` with a try-catch to handle the case where the user enters something which is not parseable as an `int`.

With Python 2.x, the `input()` function will raise an exception if the input is empty (or EOF), so you could do this instead:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    except:
        break
    m.append(n)
```